Can I change mint authority from null to an address
I have created an SPL token, minted some tokens and then paused the minting by setting authority to null.
Can I reset the authority to my/some other wallet from Null ?
I am using SPL through javascript.

Once mint authority has been disabled, it is impossible to set it again.
More information at the "disable future minting" step at https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token
